# Streaming null fields into kafka using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

when writing a dataframe to kafka topic, the columns with null value are not appearing in the published message

```py
 df.withColumn("test", f.lit(None))
```

```py
data_frame.selectExpr(
        "CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(metadata,payload)) AS value"
    ).write.format("kafka").option("topic", topic).option(
        "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https"
    ).option(
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server
    ).option(
        "kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
        f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{username}" password="{password}";',  # pylint: disable=C0301
    ).option(
        "kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN"
    ).option(
        "kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"
    ).mode(
        "append"
    ).save()
```

I want to keep the columns with null values in the payload

```json
{
...
"test": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default config enables null fields ignore in JSON writes. You'll have to add the following spark config:

```
spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields false
```

[image]
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/configuration.html